# stbi_load cannot load image

Tags: c++

I'm trying to load a texture using `stbi_load()`. Here's my code:

```
int width, height, numComponents;

unsigned char* imgData = stbi_load(fileName.c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);

if (imgData == NULL)
    cout << "Cannot load texture" << endl;

//some code

//free

stbi_image_free(imgData);
```

And when I run the program, it says `Cannot load texture`. I don't know what's wrong. I am sure that the filename is a valid path, because when I write:

```
std::ifstream infile(fileName);

if (infile.good())
{
    cout << "Good" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Not good" << endl;
}
```

It produces `Good`. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code that causes `imgData` to be `NULL` (The image is a `*.jpg` file, if anybody was wondering). Any help would be highly appreciated!

Edit : I ran `stbi_failure_reason()` and it returned `progressive jpeg`. What does this mean ?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger to see where/why it fails?

Comment: @tkausl No, but just a moment ago, I ran `stbi_failure_reason()` and it returned `progressive jpeg`. What does this mean ?

Answer (score 5):

So it turns out the answer was really easy. If you read from this website : https://gist.github.com/roxlu/3077861

You'll see that `stb_image` doesn't support `progressive JPEG` image format (which I didn't even knew existed)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the stbi_image source code(https://gist.github.com/1271/970f5fe47cf721c6ce5d8b75d2840c46#file-stb_image-c):

**There're such Limitations:**

```
- no jpeg progressive support
- non-HDR formats support 8-bit samples only (jpeg, png)
- no delayed line count (jpeg) -- IJG doesn't support either
- no 1-bit BMP
- GIF always returns *comp=4
```

**As for the progressive jpeg:**

compared to standard jpeg, the main difference lies in how the image is loaded.

- The standard JPEG format loads images one line at a time, from top to bottom, and each line is already pixel perfect.
- while for the progressive jpeg, the image appears all at once as a whole, but it’ll be blurry and pixelated a first. Gradually, you will see a clear and fully loaded image.

**How to check if a jpeg file is progressive or not:**

you could follow this answer's instruction:https://superuser.com/a/1617350/1319167